# AWS Amplify API (AppsSync / GrapthQL) Error "Not Authorized to access listXbiis on type Query"

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am building a WebApp With `AWS Amplify`.
I have the following object as part of my `schema.graphql` file.

```
type Xbiis @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private,
                                  operations: [create, update, delete, read] }])
{
   id:          ID!
   name:        String!
   owner:       User!       @hasOne
   defaultRole: AccessLevel
}
```

I want to limit access and queries to only users who are logged in.
When I login with my "admin user". That created everything.  It works fine.
When I login with my second normal user I account I get the error
`Not Authorized to access listXbiis on type Query`.

Originally, Xbiis had a more complicated security model

```
type Xbiis @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: groups, groups: ["WebAppAdmin"],
                                  operations: [create, update, read, delete] },
                                { allow: public, operations: [read] }])
{
```

Could it be some semblence of of the old model in the backend still.
Even though I ran a push with Xbiis commented out in the schema file?

What is causing the permissions error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking the [AWS troubleshooting guide for unauthorized errors](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/aws-appsync-graphql-request-unauth-error)

Changing `@auth` permissions in the `schema.graphql` file doesn't change permissions.
The permissions are actually applied in the `<project root>/amplify/backend/api/<appName>/resolvers/*.vtl` files.

Since I had never added any custom resolvers logic, I just removed the folder.
It solved the problem, but the next push, didn't regenerate the folder like I had hoped it would.